# hql query for one to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, hql

This my Category Entity

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Product>product;

public Category(){

}


public Category(int id){

    this.id=id;
}

public Category(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<Product> getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(List<Product> product) {
    this.product = product;
}


private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

}
```

And this is my Product entity

```
@Entity
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable  {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Category category;

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int productId;

public int getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(int productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}


@NotEmpty
private String name;
@NotEmpty
private int price;



public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

 public int getPrice() {
    return price;
 }

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
 }

 }
```

Now you can see that there is one to many relatonship between category and product.I want to fetch a category with a product id. i wrote a query like

```
 Category c=(Category)session.createQuery("from Category c where    c.product.productId=:productId").setParameter("productId",id).list().get(0);
```

but this query is not working.what did i do wrong in the code.?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is the erroryou are getting?

Comment: illegal attempt to dereference collection [category0_.id.product] with element property reference [productId] [from com.domain.Category c where c.product.productId=:productId]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by joining the entity

```
Category c=(Category)session.createQuery(
    "select c from Category as c " +
    "inner join c.product as product " +
    "where product.productId=:productId"
).setParameter("productId",id).list().get(0);
```